# Number of 'Unique' Ways to Mix a Color Palette?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

Assume all mixtures involve colors mixed in equal amounts and base colors are already on the palette. How many ways are there of mixing k distinct colors on a paint palette where each color must be mixed with at least one other color. For example $k=3$ would have a 3 way mix, 1 mixed into 2 others, and each mixed into each of the others separately. For 4 colors there are 10 such ways. These ways of mixing can be though of as the orbits formed by the permutation of colors acting on all mixtures of k particular colors following the above restrictions. I want to count the number of these orbits.

This would be a lot less than the number of 'unique palettes by color-list' which I believe is $2^{2^{k}-k-1}$.

Comment: First you wrote that different permutations are unique palettes, then you wrote that order (and color??) don't matter. It is hard to tell what you are asking about. Could you clarify?

Comment: I deleted that sentence, It is unnecessary to understanding the question, my bad

Comment: Would give an example? I don't quite understand

Comment: I simplified the question and added an example

Comment: Say the colors are vectors $v_1,\,\ldots,\,v_n$ and a mixture is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n c_kv_k$ where $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n c_k=1$ and $c_k\ge0$. What mixtures are allowed, I don't get it from the question. Say for $2$ colors we mix $(1,0)$ with $(0,1)$ obtaining $(\frac12,\frac12)$ then mix $(\frac12,\frac12)$ with $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, obtaining $(\frac34,\frac14)$ and $(\frac14,\frac34)$ and so on ($c_i$ are weights of first color and the second, so if we take white and black for example, we can obtain all shades of gray), or not?Can you graph it or numer it or somthing?It doesn't read as it is

Comment: you can't mix mixed colors, only mixing events directly from the bases are considered